# How to use script to reload the jstree with different ajax data source

Tags: parameters, refresh, reload, jstree

In my situation,

the part of the code about data source like this:

"json_data" : {
    "ajax" : {
        "async" : false,
        "url" : "setup/locationTreeJson.htm?id=-1"
    }
}

and on the same page,this is a  element,
the goal is when i change the  value,
then use some javascript to change the datasource of the jstree like:

"setup/locationTreeJson.htm?id=[THE_VALUE_FROM_'select element']"

then reload the jstree to display the different data

so, how can I do like this?

best regards

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see some more source.  I can't get too specific without it.

I think the main issue is accessing `json_data` later for the reload, correct?

```
var jsonDataVar = { "ajax" : { "async" : false, "url" : "setup/locationTreeJson.htm?id=-1" } };

//load jstree with `jsonDataVar` in place of where you had put the literal json object before

//alter jsonDataVar
jsonDataVar['ajax']['url'] = "setup/locationTreeJson.htm?id= " + $(CSS_SELECTOR_HERE).val();

//reload tree
```

Comment: and have got a suggestion from the jstree author,he said:

Or you can set ajax.url to a function (in the latest commit) and read
the URL off the select box.

Kindest regards,
Ivan